# Numbers in file

Tags: c, parsing

Currently I am trying to count how many numbers in a file. I tried below like this:

```
while(fgets(fileContents, sizeof(fileContents)-1, fp))

        {

            if(fileContents[sizeof(fileContents)] == '\n')

                fileContents[sizeof(fileContents)] = '\0';



            if(fileContents[sizeof(fileContents)] == 32 )

                counter++;

            //parse numbers

            tokenPtr = strtok(fileContents," ");

            counter++;

        }
```

I have a string of numbers like this: 3 5 2 2 0 4 ... N
SO I do not know how many numbers there could be so I tried counting the spaces between them,
that is why you see the ASCII value #32. Any ideas? (:

Comment: `fileContents[sizeof(fileContents)]` should be `fileContents[strlen(fileContents)-1]`

Comment: Explore each character in the file and remember each *previous* character by copying it. If the current character is a digit, and the previous character is not: increase the number count.

Comment: if you have multiple numbers on a line, you need to call `strtok()` in a loop within the line.

Comment: @WeatherVane What if the next character is not a digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. implements a 2-state state machine
2. performs the desired functionality
3. cleanly compiles

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main( void )
{
    int count = 0;

    enum state { NOT_IN_NUMBER, IN_NUMBER };

    enum state currentState = NOT_IN_NUMBER;

    FILE *fp = fopen( "myInputFile.txt", "r" );
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    int ch;
    while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        //printf( "%d\n", ch ); //debugging
        if( isdigit( ch )  )
        {
            if( currentState == NOT_IN_NUMBER )
            {
                count++;
                currentState = IN_NUMBER;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            currentState = NOT_IN_NUMBER;
        }
    }

    fclose( fp );

    printf( "number of numbers: %d\n", count );
}
```

run against a file containing:

```
3 5 2 2 0 4
```

the output is:

```
number of numbers: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

`strspn(3)` should be able to do most of the legwork here I think. Here's an example of how to count the number of initial positive integers in a string:

```c
#include <string.h>

int n_nums(const char *str)
{
    int n = 0;

    do {
        /* Skip over any whitespace */
        str += strspn(str, " \t\r\n");

        if (!strspn(str, "0123456789"))
            /* Not a number, we're done */
            break;

        /* Skip over the number. */
        str += strspn(str, "0123456789");

        /* Iff the next char is NUL or whitespace, we just
         * skipped over a valid number. */
        switch (*str) {
        case '\0':
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
        case '\r':
        case '\n':
            n++;
        }
    } while (*str);

    return n;
}
```

You should be able to combine that with the loop you've started working on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd:

a) Get the file's size and memory map the file (e.g. using `mmap()`) so it's like a big array of `uint8_t`. Alternatively you could load the file into memory any other way.

b) For every byte in the array of `uint8_t`; XOR it with 0x30. This makes it so numerical characters become values in the range 0x00 to 0x09 and everything else is a larger value.

c) For every byte in the array of `uint8_t`; if it's larger than 0x09 set it to 0x00, and if it's not set it to 0x01.

d) For every byte in the array of `uint8_t`; XOR it with the next byte. After this, 0x01 represents the beginning or end of a sequence of numerical characters.

e) For every byte in the array of `uint8_t`; add its value to a counter. This gives you the number of times a sequence of (one or more) numerical digits started or ended. By dividing this count by 2 (because you only wants "starts" and not "starts and ends") you get the answer you want.

Note that all of these steps (except the first) can be done with a single loop; and are all trivial (for you or compiler) to optimize with SIMD (so a single operation like XOR can work on multiple bytes in parallel - e.g. up to 64 bytes at once for AVX-512). Because of this it'd expect performance to be dominated by data fetches (disk IO if there's "operating system's file system cache misses", CPU cache misses, etc).

Also; this will only work with simple integers (e.g. the string "$123,456,789.01" will be counted as 4 numbers and not one number); and it won't detect/will be immune to any overflows (e.g. the string "9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999" will not cause a problem but will be treated as a valid number).

Finally; this all assumes that the character encoding is ASCII or UTF-8. For any other character encoding (EBCDIC, UTF-16, ...) it will not work and will need to be modified/adjusted to suit.